# Handle JSON Body After save() on a Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In an application using the standard Ember 2.0 [DS.JSONAPISerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html), the default behaviour for the REST API responding to a `save()` is "to return an empty object ({})."[[1](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-root)]

In my case, my REST API performs some changes to the data—including assigning a bigserial int64 ID from Postgres and processing text entry to Markdown (much, much faster than Ember can). This should (has to be) synchronous/blocking.

**Is there an idiomatic approach to handling the response from `save()` on the default DS.JSONAPISerializer so that a (the) returned JSON model is stored in Ember's cache?**

From what I can see I should be overriding `normaliseSaveResponse` to achieve this when accepting a response from the server. It's not immediately clear how I should set the fields of the "just saved" model with the server-provided values, however:

```
// app/models/item.js - simplified
export default DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr("number"),
  title: DS.attr(),
  body: DS.attr(),
  // Only populated in the server response
  rendered: DS.attr(),
  createdDate: DS.attr("date"),

  normalizeSaveResponse: function(store, primaryType, payload, id, requestType) {
    // What goes here to deserialize the response into the model?
    this.id = payload.item[i].id,
    this.title = payload.item[i].title,
    this.body = payload.item[i].rendered,
  }
});
```

To sum:

- I need to populate the model's ID field with a serial ID from the server as a response to `save()`
- I also need to populate the `rendered` field with Markdown
- Date fields, etc with server validated timestamps
- Does this work when saving a single item AND multiple items?

If there's a better way to achieve this - e.g. a different method - I'm open to suggestions. The desire is to have additional validation/transforms happen on the server, return the 'corrected' response, and then have Ember save it in its own store => transition to `/model/:id`.

Comment: Did you try to simply return model from server? It works fine for me with RESTAdapter in 1.13.9

Comment: @GennadyDogaev When you say "works fine" do you mean "it automatically populates any empty fields (id, rendered, etc) with the server's JSON response from `model.save()`" - ? If so, that's great - just conflicts with my understanding of the docs.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this out: Ember Data's default behaviour is to populate the fields (empty or not) in your model with the response JSON, provided your data has the correct structure for your adapter (i.e. RESTAdapter)

e.g.

A model like the below using the `RESTAdapter`:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr("number"),
  title: DS.attr(),
  body: DS.attr(),
  // Only populated in the server response
  rendered: DS.attr(),
  // Only populated in the server response
  createdDate: DS.attr("date"),
});
```

... will have the `rendered` and `createdDate` fields populated by the server provided your response looks like the below, with one exception (noted):

```
{
  // This can be pluralized regardless of a single item or array response as Ember can deserialize it regardless
  "posts": [{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "I'm Running to Reform the W3C's Tag",
    "body": "Yehuda Katz",
    "rendered": "<some markdown>",
    // snake_case - not suitable by default
    "created_at": "2015-09-08T20:31:09Z"
  }]
}
```

You can fix this by overriding the `keyForAttribute` method on your serializer:

```
// app/serializers/application.js
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  keyForAttribute: function(key) {
    return Ember.String.decamelize(key);
  }
});
```

Ref: http://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/